# C# WebClient Download String https

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios

In the webbrowser I can normally load the following url:
`https://security.ultimatxxxx.com:443/Serverstatus.ashx`

When I do it with:

```
Webclient.DownloadStringAsync("https://security.ultimatxxxx.com:443/Serverstatus.ashx");
```

For testing purposes you can call: `ultimate-eur` instead of `ultimatxxxx`.

It does not work, but when I load a normal URL without https I have no problems.
Which argument do I have to add so that the Webclient can also download the string?

I want to use that feature in Monotouch, but language is C#.

Comment: Does it throw any exception? if yes please add it in post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just wish to accept all certificates, you'll need to set certificate check, before you make your request:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

This will accept all certificates.

Although - if you need to actually check the certificate do something like:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => 
    {
        //to check certificate
    };
```

Comment: Hi,where do i have to add this? or how do i pass this to the webclient

Comment: Service Point Manager is not available in windowsPhone. Is there a solution for a WindowsPhone App?

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason might be the fact that some website provide different result to different browser.

You can try to provide the browser information to pretend that the call is from a browser.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15";
string download = client.DownloadString("https://security.ultimatxxxx.com:443/Serverstatus.ashx");
```

Or

> you have not bind the `completedEvent` of the `Aysnc` call.