# WebClient.DownloadFile method and HTTPS - is it an HTTPS connection?

Tags: c#

Cutting out a lot of irrelevant information, the basics are that I have a web address like so:

```
https://dinglydangs.com/download.dll?request=file&name=dunderdata.csv
```

I am using `WebClient.DownloadFile to`, well, download the file. I need to know if, because it is an https link, this method is using an HTTPS connection to download the file. If not, what steps would I need to take to ensure an HTTPS connection is used?

Possibly relevant: The link itself is sent to me in an e-mail. No actual authentication is required, I simply navigate to the link and the file downloads.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WebClient Download String https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328061/c-sharp-webclient-download-string-https)

Comment: Not even remotely a duplicate of that. Read and understand both questions instead of just the subjects before proposing that one is a duplicate, please. @KyleHale

Comment: Use [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It will, indeed, confirm if its a secure connection or not.

Comment: @icemanind Fiddler appears to be telling me the protocol is HTTP and not HTTPS. What now? [Edit: Disregard, I was reading Fiddler incorrectly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebClient will use the protocol specified in the Uri you pass the download method. You don't have to do anything special to make this happen.

You can use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to verify this, by checking the connections going out from your machine.

Comment: I'm not passing a Uri to the download method. I'm using `Webclient.Downloadfile(string address, string fileName)`. @Nate

Comment: So, I said `uri` and the method accepts `address` both are a pointer to the online resource you want to download. As long the online resource link is https, the connection will be over https...

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone, use an Uri object like `new Uri(address)`, check and change the protocol in the Uri object if required, and pass it to WebClient.Downloadfile(...). Or, if your code is allergic against the Uri type, you could just do some simple string manipulation to change a "http://" protocol prefix into a "https://" prefix.

Comment: @Nate @elgonzo I've used Fiddler to check, and it's showing the protocol as HTTP. I'm not seeing any property in the `System.Uri` object for changing the protocol. How can I do this?

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment. I was reading Fiddler incorrectly.

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone, i am glad you resolved your issue. If you are still curious about the Uri thing, then sorry for the error regarding the Uri statement in my comment. You would have to utilize UriBuilder for changing the protocol: `var ub = new UriBuilder(address) { Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps };` and pass `ub.Uri` to the DownloadFile method. (This is shorter code compared to string manipulation if you have to deal with URLs which could come with or without protocol prefix, like "www.some.com" instead of "http :// www.some.com".)