# How to pass body data with UploadStringAsync C#

Tags: c#, wpf, httprequest

I'm trying pass a string in the body of my POST request using WebClient class. Below is my code:

```
protected void GetAccessToken(string client_id, string secret)
    {
        var urlEncodedSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(secret);
        var urlEncodedSid = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(client_id);

        string bodyData = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ms-app%3a%2f%2f{0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com", client_id, secret);

        string address = "https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf";
        string myParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";

        Uri URI = new Uri(address);
        System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.BaseAddress = address;

        webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webClient.Headers["Content-Length"] = "211";
        webClient.Headers["Host"] = "https://login.live.com";

        webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(uploadStringCompleted);
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", bodyData);
    }

    private void uploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string json = e.Result.ToString();
        _oAuthToken = GetOAuthTokenFromJson(json);
    }
```

When i run the application, i received the exception "The remote server returned an error: NotFound.".
I succeeded to make the same request using the Postman:
[image: Postman requisition]

Anyone know something wrong about my request? Or something that puting me on a right way!?

Comment: Have you ever used Fiddler? I would recommend using that to catch the request to see exactly what is being passed.

Comment: tc44 I never have used Fiddler, but i will search about this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure, that your content length is *211*? This is normally in bytes - the bytes of the posted data.

Comment: Yes, i'am sure. By documentation of the web service api, i need pass Content-Lenght equals to "211".

Comment: If I were you I would look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064505/requesting-html-over-https-with-c-sharp-webclient http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536352/webclient-https-issues but my guess is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328061/c-sharp-webclient-download-string-https